# Polymer Options Settings and Outcomes

Tags: dom, polymer

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[routes]]">
<div>{{item.color}} | {{item.Index}}</div>
<google-map-directions id="{{item.name}}" 
  renderer-options='{"draggable":true,"polylineOptions":{"draggable":true,"strokeColor":"{{item.color}}"},"routeIndex":1}'
 start-address="{{item.startAddress}}"
  end-address="{{item.endAddress}}"
  travel-mode="DRIVING"
  waypoints='[{"location": "Palo Alto"}, {"location": "San Mateo"}]'>
</google-map-directions>
 <div id="dirt"></div>
 </template>
```

I am creating some routes using dom-repeat. I would like these routes to have different colors. They don't. It seems as if each route is using the same renderer. How can I change the renderer for each route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the only missing piece in your code is one character for the [attribute-binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding).

In order for the [compound binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#compound-bindings) to be deserialized into a JSON object, the following is required:

- attribute-binding syntax (i.e., `$=`) even though binding to a property
- Single-quotes around the value instead of double-quotes
- the target property must be of type `Object` (which is true for [`<google-map-directions>.rendererOptions`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map?active=google-map-directions#property-rendererOptions))

```html
// template
<google-map-directions map="[[map]]"
        renderer-options$='{"draggable":true,"polylineOptions":{"draggable":true,"strokeColor":"{{item.color}}"},"routeIndex":1}'
        ... >
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map-directions.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      google-map {
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
    <template>
      <google-map map="{{map}}" latitude="37.779"
                  longitude="-122.3892"></google-map>

      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{routes}}">
        <google-map-directions map="[[map]]"
            start-address="{{item.startAddress}}"
            end-address="{{item.endAddress}}"
            travel-mode="BICYCLING"
            renderer-options$='{"draggable":true,"polylineOptions":{"draggable":true,"strokeColor":"{{item.color}}"},"routeIndex":1}'
            waypoints="{{item.waypoints}}"></google-map-directions>
      </template>

    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties: {
            routes: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [
                  {
                    color: '#0000FF',
                    startAddress: 'San Francisco',
                    endAddress: 'Mountain View',
                    waypoints: [{location: 'Palo Alto'}, {location: 'San Mateo'}]
                  },
                  {
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    startAddress: 'Oakland',
                    endAddress: 'San Jose',
                    waypoints: [{location: 'Pleasanton'}, {location: 'Union City'}]
                  },
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gwqPPL?editors=1000)</sup>

Alternatively, you could use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) that returns the appropriate renderer options based on a given color and route index:

```
// template
<google-map-directions map="[[map]]"
        renderer-options="{{_getRendererOptions(item.color, index)}}"
        ... >

// script
Polymer({
  ...
  _getRendererOptions: function(strokeColor, index) {
    return {
      draggable: true,
      polylineOptions: {
        draggable: true,
        strokeColor: strokeColor,
        routeIndex: index
      }
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map.html">
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map-directions.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      google-map {
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
    <template>
      <google-map map="{{map}}" latitude="37.779"
                  longitude="-122.3892"></google-map>

      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{routes}}">
        <google-map-directions map="[[map]]"
            start-address="{{item.startAddress}}"
            end-address="{{item.endAddress}}"
            travel-mode="BICYCLING"
            renderer-options="{{_getRendererOptions(item.color, index)}}"
            waypoints="{{item.waypoints}}"></google-map-directions>
      </template>

    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties: {
            routes: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [
                  {
                    color: '#0000FF',
                    startAddress: 'San Francisco',
                    endAddress: 'Mountain View',
                    waypoints: [{location: 'Palo Alto'}, {location: 'San Mateo'}]
                  },
                  {
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    startAddress: 'Oakland',
                    endAddress: 'San Jose',
                    waypoints: [{location: 'Pleasanton'}, {location: 'Union City'}]
                  },
                ];
              }
            }
      
          },
          _getRendererOptions: function(strokeColor, index) {
            return {
              draggable: true,
              polylineOptions: {
                draggable: true,
                strokeColor: strokeColor,
                routeIndex: index
              }
            };
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YWWVLx?editors=1000)</sup>